# How to successfully implement async and await in Swift, and whats the best method to use

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, async-await, swiftui

Basically I'm trying to create a basic login page, it will have a ContentView, which has a method that is called when the login button is pressed. What will happen is the username and password is sent to a NetworkManager class, which will assess an api, it will either return true if the password and username is correct or false if not, this will change a @Published variable too true or false. That particular variable is Observed in the ContentView to check if it's been successful with the attempted login.

I also have a couple of classes that are used to decode and encode.

Now my issue is after I called the NetworkManager to check the api I have a conditional that checks to see if the user is successful with the login but because the network call doesn't return quick enough it will always return false, how to I get the conditional to wait for the network call to return before it proceeds.

In the java/C# i would just use a Async/Await but being new to swift I've tried a few different ways but just can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Below are the three swift files I have created, the ContentView, the NetworkManager class and the classes to structure the send and return json data.
I have also changed the address of the api for obvious reasons.
Thanks

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Queue")
    
    @State private var usernameInput = ""
    @State private var passwordInput = ""
    @State private var returnType = ""
    //private var returnType = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(networkManager.usernamesAndPass)
            TextField("Enter Username", text: $usernameInput)
            TextField("Pasword", text: $passwordInput)
            Button(action: {
                self.AttempLogin()
                })
                {
                    Text("Login")
                }
        }
        
    }
    
    func AttempLogin(){
        dispatchQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
            self.networkManager.loginFunction(username: self.usernameInput, password: self.passwordInput)
        }
        dispatchQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {
            if(self.networkManager.loggedIn){
                print("You're now logged on")
            }
                else{
                    print("You aren't logged in")
                }
            }
        dispatchGroup.wait()
        print("Final")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

NetworkManager

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var loggedIn = Bool()
    
    
    func loginFunction(username: String, password: String) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com.au/TestPHP/users/login")
        
        let loginDetails = People(user_email: username, user_password: password)
         
        //CHeck to see if the guard encoding works
        let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(loginDetails)
        
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")//the JSON request
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept") // the response expected to be in JSON format
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
          if let error = error {
              print("Error took place \(error)")
              return
          }
            
          guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let getResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loggedIn = getResponse.status
                }
                
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

UserClasses

```
class Response: Codable {
    var status: Bool
    var message: String
}

class People: Codable {
    var user_emailaddress: String = String()
    var user_password: String = String()
    var status: String = String()
    var logedIn: Bool = Bool()
    var messaage: String = String()
    
    init(user_email: String, user_password: String){
        self.user_emailaddress = user_email
        self.user_password = user_password
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide, also any tuts that are really good at explaining this would be great, as I said earlier I'm pretty new at Swift, so as much information as possible would be great. My background is generally C# and Java, but its always good to try new things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add callback in login function to be informed when asynchronous operation finished, like

```
func loginFunction(username: String, password: String, onEnded: @escaping () -> () = {}) {
    var result = false

    // ... other code
    
    result = getResponse.status
    
    // ... other code

    // make sure you have this call once and definitely performed at the end, 
    // because your current implementation has many returns 
    // which prevent reporting any result
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loggedIn = result
        self.onEnded()                        // << callback
    }
```

}
so in place of call

```
func AttempLogin(){
    self.networkManager.loginFunction(username: self.usernameInput, password: self.passwordInput) {
        // will be received at the login processed
        if self.networkManager.loggedIn {
            print("You're now logged on")
        }
        else{
            print("You aren't logged in")
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: actually you don't need either group or explicit queue for call, because URLSession executes data task asynchronously, already.*

Comment: Its all looks ok except the self.onEnded() created the error - 'Value of type 'NetworkManager' has no member 'onEnded', but its in the header so not sure why its creating an error..

Comment: If i remove the self from the onEnded() it stops the error but it never goes through the if statement as true.

Comment: I had the DispatchQueue in the wrong spot, so its all working now. Thanks..